# Make the review notification icon redirect to the queue of my choice

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, top-bar

In Stack Overflow there is a notification icon with a number that you can easily click and jump into the reviewing process.

Can we be allowed to customize the queue you get redirected to?

I can see that the "Close Votes section" is full and thus, I would like to get to that queue directly, rather than the 'old' way if possible.

Comment: I searched a while around meta but couldn't find something similar. Sorry.

Comment: From my understanding, it's currently hard-coded to the edit review queue because those are time-sensitive, so it's important that people get notified.

Comment: @Charles Sure. This is what I understand as well. But the time sensitive queue most of the times is active for 1 - 5 minutes and following any second flow in the site forces you to go all over again (click review->choose etc). 

Btw when that queue is empty you get a no reviews available message plus the icon disappears.

Comment: Plus I just read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue

Comment: You could always just leave the tab open. I'd be more inclined to support a request for the "review" link to be a mini dropdown with the six choices listed there.

Comment: @mhlester Sure that's an option as well.