# Daily review limit and burning down review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, vote-to-close

After  Shog9♦'s [Let's burn down the close queue!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) topic, I guess some alterations might be done to daliy limit for close reviews, since [some Stack Overflowians reach the limit in short time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue#comment728349_223497).

Base Idea is, giving some extra review turns to some users (yeah, some extra lives to rescue the princess in the castle). Of course, it would be better if we have some prerequisites for that like:

- *Steward badge for close review:* To keep badge hunters away. Basic idea is; robo-reviewers are badge hunters and they wil not wish to spend more time in close reviews after they got what they can as a badge.
- *A good success rate in close review audits:* not sure about the number but *x* success in 10 audit may mean a good reviewer
- *Maybe some more:* ...

Also some limitations can be set for reviews beyond normal 40. Below are based on the idea that the user already have Steward badge.

- *Tag filter:* The tags user have at least 400 (?) close reviews. If there is no tag which suits that criteria, than 1 most reviewed tag with 200+ review count. Idea is; user will be better to review on the tags he/she was active most as a close-reiewer
- *Category filter [Duplicate, off-topic, unclear what you're asking, too broad, primarily opinion based]:* All categories the user have at least 300 (?) close reviews. If there is no category which suits that criteria, then the category which the user is most active.

The base logic of the filtering is, after some reviewing, it is possible that users care may distracted because of reviewing too many questions. Using a filter will offer the user close candidates that are he would probably better that the other ones.

Users having all the prerequisited requirements may have some extra close votes.

Comment: Also if you like see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223654/change-the-default-review-notification-icon-redicect-queue-to-something-else

Comment: …and possibly give a few reviews to good 2kers? (Or maybe me?)